# Convert datetime format in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have a date in this format: `13-JUL-2016 14:38:39,969962 +00:00`
And I want the date in this format `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS`
I used the request below:

```
select to_date('13-JUL-2016 14:38:39,969962 +00:00',DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS) from dual
```

But I received the following error:

> 16:57:51  ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Comment: You need single quotes around the format string.

Comment: you didn't quote the format, so you're doing `dd divided by mm divided by yyyy` etc..., and none of those "fields" exist in `dual`. and of cousre, your format doesn't match the input string, so even if you had quoted the format, it wouldn't be able to parse your date string in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The input string is too long to go into a `date`, so I think you'll need to make it a timestamp and then `to_char` that to get the date format you want:

```
select to_char
       ( to_timestamp_tz('13-JUL-2016 14:38:39,969962 +00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS,FF TZH:TZM')
       , 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) as converted_date
from dual;

CONVERTED_DATE
-------------------
13/07/2016 14:38:39
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the output as a `char` given the following:

```
select
to_char(to_date(substr('13-JUL-2016 14:38:39,969962 +00:00',1,20), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as char_date_format
 from dual;
```

output:

```
CHAR_DATE_FORMAT    
------------------- 
13/07/2016 14:38:39
```